# How to disable urlencode query parameter guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

maybe someone has experienced the same problem, I want to make a GET request by sending data in the url parameter,

the endpoint need request like this:

```
https://test.com/sales/transaction/?page=1&pageSize=1&transactionDateFrom=2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z&transactionDateTo=2023-01-24T15:59:59.000Z
```

but if i send from guzzle using dynamics data, the request is like this:

```
https://test.com/sales/transaction/?page=1&pageSize=5&transactionDateFrom=2023-01-2500%3A00%3A00.000Z&transactionDateTo=2023-01-2523%3A59%3A59.000Z
```

my code to send request:

```
$req = $client->request('GET','https://test.com/sales/transaction/', [
        'query' => [
            'page'                  => 1,
            'pageSize'              => 5,
            'transactionDateFrom'   => 2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z,
            'transactionDateTo'     => 2023-01-24T15:59:59.000Z
        ],
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
```

how to resolve the timezone format to normal string like this

transactionDateFrom=2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z&transactionDateTo=2023-01-24T15:59:59.000Z

maybe someone has solved this problem before and can provide some information, thanks

Comment: Can you quote your date/time like so `'transactionDateFrom'   => '2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z', ...` and try to send the URL it generates?

Comment: it can, but in the future I will use data from the $fromDate and $toDate variables which are of type string, should I still use the quote ''? - @zedfoxus

Comment: I don't know how guzzle works. We can find out. Before you call `$req = $client->...`, do `$fromDate = '2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z'; $toDate = '2023-01-24T15:59:59.000Z'` and then in your query array, use `'transactionDateFrom' = $fromDate, ...` and see if guzzle generates the correct URL. If not, you may have to use `'transactionDateFrom' = "'" . $fromDate . "'", ...`. You'll have to try this out and see what works since I am not familiar with guzzle.

Comment: It'll be best to write an answer and mark that answer as accepted. You are welcome to write an answer and then accept it after a few minutes (or you can ask me to write an answer and then later accept it). That way, the answer will appear solved and others with a similar problem can find your solved answer.